# Auth0 failed to retrieve profile

Tags: angular, auth0

I have integrated auth0 by following documentation https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-angular-user-authentication/
It's always return undefined /null after successfully of login, that's so strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so strange I have integrated other library and read tutorials, but issue solved by used `this.auth.loginWithPopup();` instead `this.auth.loginWithRedirect();`